# Magento2 How to add(pass) Extra Fee in Authorize.net

Tags: magento2, checkout, configuration, payment, authorize.net

I have created a code for an extra fee of payment method and its working with all payment method except Authorize.net I have also configure with PayPal and pass the extra fee on this. I want same like create in Authorize.net. how to pass the extra fee in Authorize.net payment method.

Comment: I don't think you need, for PayPal it is need. Can you share your code of model/quote/total and that file name

Comment: you need to add in grand total ? or add field in payment gateway call ?

Comment: add a field in the payment gateway. in grand total already added payment process is fail but in admin side display order in this order extra field is not set.